# How to temporarily give sysadmin to a user?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Below code is in a stored procedure and gives the following error when run under user: premfguser.
Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted.

```
SET @provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
SET @ExcelString = 'Excel 8.0;Database=' + @fn

EXEC('INSERT INTO OPENROWSET(''' + @provider + ''',''' + @ExcelString + ''',''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:L2]'') 
SELECT [ITEMNUMBER],'''',[ITEM_DESCRIPTION],[CASEPACK],[UNIT PRICE],[CASE PRICE],[WEIGHT],[CUBE],[CASE DIMS],[UPC],[CASE UPC],[Q Comments] FROM [ORDER SUMMERY] WHERE [Order #] = ''' + @OrderNumber + '''')
```

When I add premfguser to sysadmin it works. How can I run this code without permanently giving sysadmin to premfguser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use EXECUTE AS **and** sign the procedure with a certificate. See [this example](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) for how to sign a procedure, see also this article [Signing Procedures with Certificates](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html#Certificates) and this [Tutorial: Signing Stored Procedures with a Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283630.aspx).

Note that the alternative of marking the database TRUSTWORTHY means that the `dbo` of the database is a  de-facto `sysadmin`, as he can escalate himself to sysadmin anytime he likes if the trustworthy bit is set. Code signing is a much better alternative, although significantly more complex.

Answer (score 1):

When you define the stored procedure, add the `EXECUTE AS` clause:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcedure
WITH EXECUTE AS 'UserName'
AS BEGIN
  -- procedure code as usual...
END;
```

Comment: I tried that. Username has role sysadmin. I get the following error: `Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted`